# Why we can double elements in the table?

Tags: binary-operations

If we perform an operation on ordered pair from set A={1,2,3,4}, we can built a table like this:
[image]

But, since set A is finite and there is only one element "1", "2" etc., why we can double elements in the table? An operation cannot be perform like this: 1*1, because we have only one "1".
In other words, my question is: what we choose from given set A: an ordered pair OR each element of an ordered pair?

Comment: It seems like you're looking at an operator $\oplus$ that is defined for $a \oplus b$, $a \neq b$, right? Usually operators are not defined this way, for example normal addition and multiplication do accept the same element on both sides.

Comment: Actually I though about :□. First number gets multiplied by itself, plus second number. And I think this kind of table is illegitimate in such case.

Comment: Well, the symbol doesn't matter here. I just chose a generic symbol, because I don't know what kind of operator you are talking about.

Comment: Choosing an element from a set does not "consume" it. Following your reasoning to the absurd, after having written the column headers, the set $A$ would be empty.

Answer (score 2):

An operation on $A$ is a mapping from $A\times A$ to $A$. Since $(1,1)$ is an element of $A\times A$, $1*1$ is defined.

There is nothing in the definition of an operation that would forbid us from "doubling" elements in the table. That, in essence, is the only answer we can give to the question

> why we can double elements in the table?

Comment: What does it mean: "An operation on AA is a mapping from A×AA×A to A"?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Which part of that sentence is unclear to you? Do you know what a mapping is? Do you know what $A\times A$ is?

Comment: The question is what we choose from given set A: an ordered pair OR each element of an ordered pair.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk You didn't answer my question.

Comment: "is" is unclear to me: why an operation on AA is a mapping from A×AA×A to A

Comment: @JosefKlimuk That's the *definition* of an operation. That's how, in mathematics, operations on sets are defined.